# Which number is the odd-one-out in the above set?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, number-sequence

[image]

In this number set there is something common between the numbers that makes them up into a pattern.
Which one of these numbers break up the hidden pattern?

Comment: it is simple mathematical question not puzzle..

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Being simple is not the same as being *not a puzzle*. I'm not sure why you're linking me to a comment on a totally different question. You might like to learn about [this site's policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373) regarding "maths problems" (off-topic) vs "maths puzzles" (on-topic).

Comment: @Randal'Thor it seems like textbook maths problem to me, and you may be different views but it seems to be true to me... leave the job to other moderators and viewers you have justified your views... we are not here to argue... I can post 100 of questions like these...  odd one out of series...

Comment: @SayedMohdAli With all due respect, you may want to find out a bit more about the folks you're talking to before you presume to correct them on how this site works. Rand al'Thor is correct here. The general tone of the comments I removed from this question—and many other comments I've seen from you on other more recent puzzles—suggest perhaps you are "here to argue". Please take some time to look around, observe how other users answer and comment, and reflect on comments that have been made to you. Our community likes to be helpfully constructive in feedback to newer users. You might listen.

Comment: @Rubio we can talk on chat there is something I would like to discuss with you. Rand al'thor, is a very nice person and i have no problem with him and i will do agree with him...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is

> The **11** tile
>
>  Because it is the only number which cannot have a GCD (greatest common divisor) greater than $1$ when paired with any other tile.